# Many includes slow down website?

Tags: php

I am creating a cms system.
In my index.php page i am including my content, menu links dynamically. 
My plugins are also loaded via the index.php page. Now there are lets say 200 includes in the php index page. the plugins only load when the tag is displayed on a page in the cms. But now my question is if so many includes in my index.php page slow down my website?

Comment: Yes it will slowdown if you are including the script from other servers.Especially plugins.What you can do is to download thse files and keep them in your application and include it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes includes can slow a website down, but it can be combatted with the use of a cache system.

On my CMS, I created a Template Parser which handles all the generation of HTML and is used across includes. But by having a cache implemented which saves a copy of the HTML output which has an expiry of 10 mins. and is automatically wiped when content is updated; it reduces the amount of times your code needs to run and those includes are only included when actually needed.

I use this on my current site http://www.chris-shaw.com

Comment: and if i just require_once the files, is that better than including files

Comment: It can help if there’s a possibility of your included file being included repeatedly. I don’t use require once as I only declare them ones usually at the top of the file where possible.

Answer (score 3):

Every PHP file you include will have to be parsed and executed, along with any PHP files they in turn include.  None of this can happen in 0 time, and the more you include the more workload your server will have to do to generate the page to be displayed.

Most content on pages tends to actually be static so a caching strategy of some sort may be in order.

Answer (score 1):

yes it will slow down your site...

Source(s):

[Will including unnecessary php files slow down website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198253/will-including-unnecessary-php-files-slow-down-website)

http://www.webmaster-talk.com/threads/111789-Do-too-many-PHP-includes-slow-down-your-website

Answer (score 1):

there is a topic about it.
[Will including unnecessary php files slow down website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198253/will-including-unnecessary-php-files-slow-down-website?rq=1)

i you include from other servers then yes it will slow you down, but if you include within the server, then its like copying the included code into your index.php, check the topic.